# How to continue allowing jquery ajax request on clicking different links?

Tags: jquery, html, express, onclick

So far I have created code to do ajax request and pull information from the server. I can clicks link and it'll bring me to a page, ajax style, header and footer do not refresh, however when I click another link, it breaks and the page refreshes. I need ajax to work so that the music player, which is in the footer, will continue to play from page to page.

I've tried: bind and unbind on my links, on(click) and off(click), $.ajax(url, success: function(results)), $.get(url, function(data))

I think it may have something to do with my links as i'm not sure if im binding, unbinding, and rebinding them correctly. I been searching all day and exhausted.

Another thing to note. Some links are just domain.com/page/ and others are domain.com/folder/page, i'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Codeblocks: This is my most recent attempt.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    linkHref = $(this).attr('href'); // gets url for ajax get request
    linkHtml = $(this).html(); // I just grabbed this for the url updater

    $.get(linkHref, function(data){
        $('#lkobody').html(data);  //wrapper of my content, so stuff here gets replaced by requested page 
        }
    ).done(function(){
        // Updates my url after the ajax does it's thing.
        window.history.replaceState('Larry King Orchestra', linkHtml, linkHref);
        $('a').off('click'); //trying to turn the click off so I can use it again.
    });

    return false;
});
```

Also to note, when I'm in my browser console, I can constantly paste the $.get and $.ajax blocks I made, simply changing the page url I request, and it works flawlessly. Just when I try to click using the links... It fails on the second click and completely reloads the page.

Note: Listening to the same song over and over is killing me... Torture... Please save me...

Oh if there is any additional information you need, other than my creditcard and ssn, I'll provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this solves your problem, or if I understood your question correctly however a few things I noticed:

When you use `.on('click'..)` it will only bind the click event to the links on the page at that time, if you dynamically load content you will need to re-bind the click event.
Essentially calling this again in the ajax callback:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){});
```

Rather than constantly rebinding you can bind it to the document like so:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault() // prevent the default behavior of the link
      // magic here 
});
```

This will guarantee the event will be bound to any new 'a' elements as well.
However, I would strongly suggest to not bind an ajax request to every 'a' element but rather use classes instead as this will give you more control over what is happening. Example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function(e){
          e.preventDefault() // prevent the default behavior of the link
          // magic here 
});
```

And then give any content links the class 'ajaxLink'

Comment: I'm getting my web team to plus 1 you for this. It works like a charm! Thank You So Much!!! I'll keep in mind about the classes so I don't run into future problems!